# Check mock called with runtime object create

Tags: python, mocking, pymock

I have code for cassandra cluster like

```
cluster = Cluster(
        config.CASS_CLUSTER,
        load_balancing_policy=policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(
            config.CASS_D_CENTER))
```

When I write UT for this and try to check `Cluster` call with my parameter.

```
mock_cluster.assert_called_with(
    config.CASS_CLUSTER,
    load_balancing_policy=policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(
        config.CASS_D_CENTER))
```

It gives error.

```
AssertionError: Expected call: Cluster(['192.168.1.1'], load_balancing_policy=<cassandra.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy object at 0x106fa2ed0>)
Actual call: Cluster(['192.168.1.1'], load_balancing_policy=<cassandra.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy object at 0x106fa2cd0>)
```

I get this because both object are different, is there any way to check `called_with` in mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mock_cluster.assert_called_with(
    config.CASS_CLUSTER,
    load_balancing_policy=mock.ANY)
```